# java conversion between custom types

Tags: java, class

I was wondering what the best way is to convert a custom class to another.
f.e. :

```
public class TypeA { 
   String test;
}

public class TypeB { 
   String test;
}
```

2 different ways :

```
 public TypeA convert(TypeB input) {

 TypeA data = null;
 if (input != null) {
      data = new TypeA();
      data.setTest(input.getTest());
 }
 return data;
 }



 public TypeA convert(TypeB input) {

 final TypeA data;
 if (input != null) {
      data = new TypeA();
      data.setTest(input.getTest());
 } else {
      data = null;
 }
 return data;
 }
```

There is no functional difference between these 2 methods, I just want to know if 1 of these 2 is better and why.

Thanks

Comment: How tight do you want the coupling to be?

Comment: as lightly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm honest, I'd rather do this in the `constructor`.

**Example**

```
public TypeA(TypeB typeB) {
    if(typeB != null) {
        this.test = typeB.getTest();
    }       
}
```

Comment: actually yes. the null check is stupid...  recently read on SO an accusation that beginner Java programmers aggressively let things be null and null check.

Comment: I would not recommend that, as it enforces a strong coupling between the two types. One of them could be your domain model and the other a DTO, which is unlikely what you want to achieve.

Comment: I used a really simple example here, it's not possible to do it the constructor due to high number of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Instance members are automatically initialized by its default values. For object default value is `null`.

---

The local variable are not initialized by default. If you create a final variable then you have to set the value.

In first option you can't make it final because you can't assign it again.

In second option you have to initialize it before returning because its a final variable.

You can use either one.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there are four approaches, depending on how tight you want you classes have coupled.

1) Use a *copy constructor*:

Note, that this term means to copy an instance, so that both are the same class. But it still works here also.

```
class TypeA {
    String test;
    TypeA(TypeB input) {
        this.test = input.test;
    }
}

class TypeB {
    String test;
}
```

2) Use a static *from* method in `TypeA`:

This is essentially the same as the constructor, but might fit better, as you are free to design your constructors.

```
class TypeA {
    String test;
    private TypeA() { /* private for demonstration purposes */ }
    static TypeA fromTypeB(TypeB input) {
        TypeA a = new TypeA();
        a.test = input.test;
        return a;
    }
}

class TypeB {
    String test;
}
```

3) Use a static *to* method in TypeB:

This approach uses a conversion technique that is also seen in many libraries, including the JRE itself. Have a look at [`Collection.toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

```
class TypeA {
    String test;
}

class TypeB {
    String test;
    static TypeA toTypeA() {
        TypeA a = new TypeA();
        a.test = this.test;
        return a;
    }
}
```

4) Use a conversion method as you did. The advantage is to not have any coupling between `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

---

Which one you really choose, depends on your design, on your needs, and on the purposes of those classes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but in my case I don't want to add any more methods to the class itself because my classes are very complex.

Answer (score 0):

For members of a class which are references to memory locations, you may wish to call the clone() method, in order to construct a new version of that field in memory (so that when you change the instance of TypeA, the field in the TypeB instance stays the same).  I am **not** suggesting to override the clone method of either class (for clarity).  Otherwise, the conversion functions are almost identical and are down to the readability from the perspective of the author.

Comment: It sounds like you are suggesting to implement the `clone()` method on `ClassA` to return an instance of `ClassB` - this really shouldn't be done, as it breaks the contract of `clone()` and can give all sorts of headaches... If this is not what you are suggesting, you should clarify your answer...

Comment: I am suggesting that members of a class, which are references to memory locations, should be cloned when a class is copied, so as to avoid aliasing the reference.  I shall further clarify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a conversion system that couples as lightly as possible, look into how Eclipse itself does it, using separate classes that [handle the conversions from one type to another](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fdatabinding%2Fconversion%2FIConverter.html); have a central registy that can give you a converter from `Class<A>` to `Class<B>`.